# Homeomorphism between two locally compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two locally compact spaces. Define $\phi:X_1\to X_2$. Suppose $\phi$ is bijective and continuous. I know that if $X_1$ is compact, I can conclude $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. But in this case that $X_1$ is a locally compact space I do not know $\phi$ is a homeomorphism or not. Please regard me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a continuous bijection $[0,1) \to S^1$ given by $t \mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$, both spaces are locally compact, but it's not a homeomorphism.

Comment: The circle, $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$.

Comment: No, that's not a bijection ($x^{1/2}$ is always nonnegative...). I'm trying to show you a counterexample to the claim: both $[0,1)$ and $S^1$ are locally compact.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm studying a theorem. it wants to show there is a homeomorphism between two locally compact. for this he just show the function is bijective and open and then concludes that it's a homeomorphism. so how does he conclude it?

Comment: If $f:X_1 \to X_2$ is continuous, open and bijective then it is a homeomorphism. Are you having trouble with how he concludes the map is open or how he concludes it is a homeomorphism from the fact that it is open, bijective, and continuous? The former is the tough part and the latter is obvious.

Could you include the author's proof that the map is open?

Comment: @Pelto :The author does not show the function is continuous, so I can not conclude that it's homeomorphism.

Comment: Not to cause any offense but a bijective open map obviously has a continuous inverse. So if the author clearly showed the map $\phi$ is open then yeah proof is done.